# sequence of open sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Find the sequence of open sets in $\Bbb{R}$ like $\{G_n\}$ such that $\Bbb{Z}=\bigcap _{n=1} ^{\infty}G_n$.

I think an answer is this:
$$G_n=\bigcup_{m=1} ^{\infty}(m-\tfrac{1}{n+1},m+\tfrac{1}{n+1})$$ 
where $m\in\Bbb{Z}$, $n \in \Bbb{N}$, and $ \Bbb{Z}\subseteq \cap_{n=1} ^{\infty}{G_n} $ because $\{i\}=\cap_{n=1} ^{\infty}(i-\frac{1}{n+1},i+\frac{1}{n+1})$ for any $i\in\Bbb{Z}$, but I can't prove that $\cap_{n=1} ^{\infty}{G_n}\subseteq\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: That's basically correct, except you did $\Bbb N$ instead of $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
$$
G_n=\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\Bigl(m-\frac{1}{n+1},m+\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigr)
$$
If $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $m\in G_n$ for all $n$, so $m\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}G_n$.

Suppose now $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x$ is not an integer. Let $k$ be the maximum integer such that $k<x$ and verify that, if
$$
\frac{1}{n+1}<\min\{x-k,k+1-x\},
$$
then $x\notin G_n$ (this needs a check I leave to you).

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\not\in \Bbb{Z}$, let $m$ be its nearest integer. $\exists\space N=\frac{1}{|x-m|}+2$ s.t. $x\not\in G_N$ and thus $x\not\in\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n$. So $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}G_n\subseteq\Bbb{Z}$.